# Replace password prompt with Touch ID to read Keychain password

Tags: password, keychain, script, touch-id

I'm using the following command to fetch a password from the Keychain in a shell script: `security find-generic-password -w -s "MyServiceName"`

It works, but it's showing a popup window asking me for the login keychain password:

> `security` wants to use your confidential information stored in
>   "MyServiceName" in your keychain. To allow this, enter the "login"
>   keychain password.
>
> With the options to `Deny`, `Allow` or `Always Allow`

But I don't want to enter my keychain password every time, so I can't use "Allow" and I'd rather not "Always Allow" in order to keep some level of security here.

Ideally I'd like to get a Touch ID prompt instead. Is there any way to do this ?

Comment: That would be great ! Did you find anything?

Comment: I'm not sure that this answers your question, but you can have sudo use TouchID instead of a password dialog, see here: http://osxdaily.com/2017/11/22/use-touch-id-sudo-mac/

Answer (score 7):

Investigating this I was not able to find any method that would allow for the `security` command to make use of Touch ID. This article titled: [How to Use Touch ID to Authenticate sudo on Mac OS](http://osxdaily.com/2017/11/22/use-touch-id-sudo-mac/), mentioned in a comment regarding `sudo` and then use of the Touch ID, will not work here since that makes use of the addition of this line:

```
auth sufficient pam_tid.so
```

to `sudo`'s PAM file, `/etc/pam.d/sudo`. There is nothing equivalent to the `security` command since it doesn't make use of `sudo`.

Therefore you're left with using one of the 2 methods mentioned in the dialog when running the `security` command:

- Always Allow
- Allow

[image: ss1]

If you pick "Always Allow" this will grant access indefinitely just to the `security` command. If you pick "Allow" it will grant `security` access just 1 time to Keychain.

#### Example

Here I've created an application password item in Keychain called TestPassword.

[image: ss2]

We can see that nothing has been given access to it by looking at the ACL tab of this dialog.

[image: ss3]

If I run this `security` command:

```
$ security find-generic-password -w -s "TestPassword"
```

And permanently "Always Allow" I'll be given the password for this item from Keychain:

```
TestPassword123
```

But more importantly I'll add `security` to the ACL for this item in Keychain.

[image: ss4]

Comment: _I'll add security to the ACL for this item in Keychain._
I believe this is very insecure because then any app/script in a system can call the `security` command and read your data.