# Unlock keychain with Touch ID

Tags: macbook-pro, keychain, touch-id

Is there a way to authenticate with Touch ID instead of password on Macbook Pro when I need to unlock the keychain?

Comment: Could you clarify exactly what you mean by "unlock the keychain"? Is this in the context of Keychain Access, or a web browser, or somewhere else?

Comment: @timothymh When an application needs to access a password stored in the keychain it asks you to unlock it. You get a message saying "XXX wants to use the login keychain". To unlock it you need to type your password. I am asking if you can unlock it with Touch id instead of password.

Comment: Possible duplicate - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/311334/replace-password-prompt-with-touch-id-to-read-keychain-password

Answer (score 3):

Natively, I believe MacOS prohibits this in order to increase security (Touch ID is less secure than a standard passcode in most situations). However, I know there's and app called Unlox (http://unlox.it) that will let you unlock your Keychain using Touch ID on your iPhone. This leads me to believe it is possible to do this with a 3rd party application of some kind.

Comment: Why is Touch ID less secure? You need to physically be there and you are immune to keyloggers.

Comment: Touch ID is still very secure. However, it’s much easier to fake someone’s finger print than it is to get their password. Someone with the right resources could life your prints off the laptop and use it to unlock your device.

Comment: For extreme scenarios, "the secrete in one's head" is safer than "something unique one owns". One can keep the secrete as long as they are tough enough, but a bad guy can easily (easy for them) get access to your fingertip, with or without your consent.